# Программное нажатие на элемент Options Menu

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Есть `Options Menu` с различными элементами. Как можно программно нажать на один из них? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вызвать метод `onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(R.id.your_id_action));` при этом `menu` должна быть глобальной переменной которая инициализируется при создании меню, но можно сделать проще вынести весь код в отдельный метод и вызывать его в нужный момент